# Has debido estudiar duro

Tags: verbos, significado

I have recently read the following sentence:

> Has debido estudiar y practicar duro.

The literal translation of the expression "has debido estudiar" is "you had to study", but I think the speaker meant "you probably studied" instead in this context. Can the verb "deber" be used to express a (past?) likely event ?

Comment: A very common mistake is mixing "deber" and "deber de"

Comment: Just in case, Fundeu's article about it....[Deber + infinitivo expresa obligación o suposición y deber de + infinitivo solo indica suposición, tal como recoge el Diccionario panhispánico de dudas.](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/deber-de-infinitivo-obligacion-suposicion/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según el [diccionario panhispánico de dudas](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=deber), la lengua culta admite también el uso sin preposición «de» con el sentido de suposición, que se tiende a omitir para evitar cacofonías como «debe de decir». Por tanto, la frase  del ejemplo es ambigua, pero no incorrecta. Actualmente,  el error posible (y frecuente) es usar «deber de» con el sentido de obligación, pero no al contrario:

> Has debido estudiar duro.

(Supongo que has estudiado duro.) ✔ CORRECTO

(Tenías que haber estudiado duro.) ✔ CORRECTO

> Has debido **de** estudiar duro.

(Supongo que has estudiado duro.) ✔ CORRECTO

(**Tenías que** haber estudiado duro.) ✗ **INCORRECTO**

Es decir, «deber» más infinitivo expresa obligación o suposición, según el contexto:

> Has debido pasar miedo ¿verdad?

(Supongo que has pasado miedo).

> ¡Has debido coger el dinero, idiota!

(Tenías que haber cogido el dinero).

Mientras «deber de» más infinitivo solo indica suposición.

> Has debido de pasar miedo ¿verdad?.

(Supongo que has pasado miedo).

> ¡Tú has debido de coger el dinero, ladrón!

(Supongo que tú has cogido el dinero)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! Yo no conocía ese significado de "deber de". "debes haber estudiado mucho" es correcto/usual y significa lo mismo? Puedes incluir el enlace al diccionario panamericano de dudas, dónde se dice que "debe" puede ser usado en lugar de "debe de" ?

Comment: Gracias por el enlace, pero no contestaste mi pregunta en mi comentario anterior: "debes (de) haber estudiado mucho" es igual a "has debido (de) estudiar mucho" ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista  sin más contexto, "debes haber estudiado", incluso sin preposición, es una combinación de tiempos que se presta a interpretarlo solo como suposición. Por contra, "debiste/deberías/deberás haber estudiado"  se empleará casi siempre con el sentido de obligación,  incluso si va (mal)  acompañado con  "de". Pero  "has debido estudiar"  es totalmente ambiguo, y con "de" se aclara (bien) que es una suposición.

Answer (score 1):

To express a supposition or make an assumption about an event use "deber de". Use "deber" to express an obligation or requirement.

So for your example sentence, one can say:

```
debes de haber estudiado duro.
you must have studied hard.
```

Comment: Please read Fran's reply. "deber" alone can also be used to express deduction.